# Private Struct only returnable with private listed first in a class

Tags: c++

So I have run into the case where returning an object of type Node is not allowed if the private variables have been listed after the public as can be seen by the two screenshots below. There CLion is giving me an error as can be seen with Node being red. I understand why this is, however I am wondering if there is anyway to fix this issue without placing/declaring private before public?

Public before private (Desired):
[image]

Private before public (what works):
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post the text. Also, "live" error messages in C++ are notoriously unreliable. Trust the compiler, not the IDE.

Comment: @molbdnilo I appreciate the feedback, I included pictures instead of text so the difference in color could be noted showing the error, but I can include it in text form as well if that would be good. Also, the compiler gives the same error, generally Clion is very reliable in its "live" warnings, but I will take that note into consideration when using other IDEs! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that when the return type `Node*` is encountered in the member function `getCurrentPalyer` definition, the compiler doesn't know that there is a struct named `Node`. So you've to tell that to the compiler which you can do by adding a **forward declaration** for `Node` as shown below:

```
class Palyer 
{ private: struct Node;    //forward declaration added for Node
  public:
    
    Node* func()
    {
        return head;
    }
  private:
    struct Node {};
    Node* head;
};
```

[Working Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/hJpqvwi9H)